# TeamCity: Disable trigger by schedule

Tags: teamcity

I have VCS trigger which works perfect. But I want disable it every day from 20.00 till 6.00. (Server at night perform some performance critical tasks and developers rarely commit after 20.00)

Is it possible?

Comment: Disable the build agent on the server during the performance critical tasks. Problem solved.

Comment: Is it possible disable/enable agent by schedule? I do not see such option...   I do not want do it manually every evening :)

Comment: Not that I know, but that can easily covered by a cronjob. Or you could create two build configurations with a schedule, one that executes the disable script and one that executes the enable script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [Schedule Trigger](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Schedule+Triggers) and use cron expression to specify your rules.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Schdule Trigger can disable/suppress VCS trigger? I want to continue starting builds by VCS trigger but only in working hours. From documentation I assume that Schdule Trigger will start builds along with VCS started builds.

Comment: I thought you have VCS trigger which runs build after each commit. Am I right?  So you can create Schedule Trigger(instead of VCS Trigger) to run build Mon-Fri between 6:00 to 20:00 every 60 seconds only when there are pending changes.